# Configurable Product Price correct on Product Page, but wrong in Checkout

Tags: checkout, simple-product, onestepcheckout

When configuring a product on the product page, the price works out whatever the price of the product is plus the combined amount of options added which is correct.

but when I add the product to the checkout, it will show the wrong price. I am trying to fix the issue , but i am not getting how to fix it.

The price in the checkout is working out:

item + option[1]
item + option[2]
item + option[3] +
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
£1,725.99

instead of:

item
option[1]
option[2]
option[3]+
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
£927.99

the site is using onestepcheckout and also simple-product. 
I don't think these are the issues as when I turn onestepcheckout off, i still have the same problem.

I hope this makes sence, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, maybe a bit of a hack but it seems to work. I thought I'd post an answer in case anyone else has the same problem.

In: *`app/code/local/Magecomp/AbsolutePricing/Model/Product/Type/Price.php`*

Change this:

```
protected function _applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice)
{
    if ($optionIds = $product->getCustomOption('option_ids')) {
        $basePrice = $finalPrice;
        $finalPrice = 0;
        foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
            if ($option = $product->getOptionById($optionId)) {

                $quoteItemOption = $product->getCustomOption('option_'.$option->getId());
                $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                    ->setOption($option)
                    ->setQuoteItemOption($quoteItemOption);
                //Mage::log('Option Type : '.$option->getType());
                $price = $group->getOptionPrice($quoteItemOption->getValue(), $basePrice);
                //Mage::log('getOptionPrice : '.$price);
                $finalPrice += $price;
                //Mage::log('_applyOptionsPrice : '.$finalPrice);
            }
        }
    }

    return $finalPrice;
}
```

To this:

```
protected function _applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice)
{
    if ($optionIds = $product->getCustomOption('option_ids')) {

        //used to count how many options, we divide the base price by to get correct value 
        $numberOfOptions = count(explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()));

        $basePrice = $finalPrice / $numberOfOptions;
        $finalPrice = 0;

        foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
            if ($option = $product->getOptionById($optionId)) {
                $quoteItemOption = $product->getCustomOption('option_'.$option->getId());
                $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                    ->setOption($option)
                    ->setQuoteItemOption($quoteItemOption);
                //Mage::log('Option Type : '.$option->getType());
                $price = $group->getOptionPrice($quoteItemOption->getValue(), $basePrice);
                //Mage::log('getOptionPrice : '.$price);
                $finalPrice += $price;
                //Mage::log('_applyOptionsPrice : '.$finalPrice);
            }
        }
    }

    return $finalPrice;
}
```

This counts the number of selected options and divides the final price by the result of `$numberOfOptions`.

I hope this helps! :)